# Position of TRY/CATCH bloc for SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, try-catch

I would like to know the best position of a `TRY/CATCH` for a T-SQL procedure and why

In the statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name        
AS         
BEGIN  
    -- Code 

    BEGIN TRY
        sql_statement  
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- Handle errors 
    END CATCH 

    --Code 
END
```

or in the call:

```
BEGIN TRY
      EXEC procedure_name   
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
      -- Handle errors 
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the first option.

```
BEGIN TRY
  sql_statement  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Handle errors 
END CATCH
```

The reason is you would want to catch the errors at the source and then take some appropriate actions.

In second option you are letting the error bubble up and there you would not have access to all the Exact error information returned by the error functions inside the catch block.

For example the `ERROR_LINE()` function will return the line number of the calling procedure where the it is calling the procedure containing the actual sql code, you would want to know the error line number where the actual exception was thrown, this information is only available in the catch block of the procedure being called.

Moral of the story is try to catch exceptions as close to the source as possible.

Comment: Just want to add that if one uses THROW in a catch block of the outer stored proc, all of the original error details of the called proc are retained.

Comment: Another downside to the second option is that you would have to repeat the error handling in the CATCH block every time you call the stored procedure, rather than the error handling being contained in the sproc.